# program cant start, methods withdraw / deposit

Tags: java, class, methods, program-entry-point

im new to methods and classes.
 I coded a withdraw/deposit program which ask for name and balance, allowing withdraw and deposit functions. eclipse doesn't allow me to run the program, why is that so?? am I suppose to create (public static void main (string[] args) on a separate class?? and if I have to, what methods(get / set) stay on this class or get transferred to main class?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bank {
private String name;
private double balance;
private double withdraw;
private double deposit;
private double withdrawTotal;
private double depositTotal;

bank()
{
    name = null;
    balance = 0;        
    withdraw = 0;
    deposit = 0;
    withdrawTotal = 0;
    depositTotal = 0;

}   

public String getname() {
    return name;
}

public double getBalance(){
    return balance;
}

//public double getAnnualInterestRate(){
    //return annualInterestRate;
//}

public double getWithdraw() {
    return withdraw;
}

public double getDeposit() {
    return deposit;
}

public double getWithdrawTotal() {
    return withdrawTotal;
}

public double getDepositTotal() {
    return depositTotal;
}

public void setname(String newname){
    Scanner namescan = new Scanner(System.in);
    name = namescan.nextLine();
}

public void setBalance(double newBalance){
    Scanner bscan = new Scanner(System.in);
    balance = bscan.nextInt();
}


public void setWithdraw(double newWithdraw){
    withdraw = newWithdraw;
}

public void setDeposit(double newDeposit){
    deposit = newDeposit;
}

public void setWithdrawTotal(double newWithdrawTotal){
    deposit = newWithdrawTotal;
}

public void setDepositTotal(double newDepositTotal){
    deposit = newDepositTotal;
}


   //calculate method

public double withdrawCalculuation() {
    return balance - withdraw;
}

public double depositCalculation(){
    return balance + deposit;
}

//public double annualInterestRateCalculation(){
//  return depositTotal * .045;
//}


public void print() {
bank account = new bank();
account.setname(name);
account.setBalance(20000.00);
account.setWithdraw(2500);
account.setWithdrawTotal(17500.00);
account.setDeposit(3000.00);
account.setDepositTotal(20500.00);
//account.setAnnualInterestRate(.045);


System.out.println("The Accound name is:" + account.getname());
System.out.println("The Balance is:" + account.getBalance());
System.out.println("Amount of withdrawal is:" + account.getWithdraw());
System.out.println("The Balance after withdrawal is:" + account.getWithdrawTotal());
System.out.println("Amount of deposit is:" + account.getDeposit());
System.out.println("The Balance after depsoit is:" + account.getDepositTotal());
//System.out.println("The monthly interest for total amount is:" + account.getAnnualInterestRate());
}



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**eclipse doesn't allow me to run the program, why is that so??**

Because JVM is not able to find the `main()` method.

**am I suppose to create (public static void main (string[] args) on a separate class??**

No. You can add your `main()` in same class.

Answer (score 3):

Please start with a Basic Java [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/). You need to have a main method to execute a java program.